# Auto Generate a ProductID along with a Sting Prefix in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Auto Generate a ProductID along with a String Prefix in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used Random function in MVC, and Solved this Problem With Following :

Firstly created a random String Generator:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

Then created a random Number Generator:

```
public static int randomNoGenerator()
{
    int ranNo = random.Next(1, 100000);
    return ranNo;
}
```

Then wherever user I Called the Above Functions:

```
string randstrng = RandomString(3);

int pRanNo = rnd.Next(1, 9999);

var productID = randstrng + pRanNo;
```

Comment: Thank you for getting me an idea and i got an answer which i rethink and reviewed myself and edited here.